# Calling back Button doesn't work the same as pressing it

Tags: android-studio

So I'm creating a game for a class project and I'm pretty new to android studio. The game has to be closed either when the back is pressed or the lives are over. Now  The "on Back Pressed" written for the code works as desired. But when I call it when the lives are over it doesn't work the same way.

The Game main code goes Like:

```
public class GameMain extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static GameMain GameMainInstance = new GameMain();
/* Some Stuff*/
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        newScore = MainThread.getMyValue();
        MainThread.SetMyValue();
        intent.putExtra("Score", newScore);
        setResult(1,intent);
        finish();
    }
```

And this works when I press the back. Now in the game creation I call a different class call "Game Thread" which I think is called a surface view.
in the render part I go like

```
 private void render(Canvas canvas) {
        if (Lives < 1)
        {
            GameMain inst = GameMain.GameMainInstance;
            inst.onBackPressed();
            Log.i("value entered", Float.toString(Lives));
        }
}
/* Some Stuff*/
```

To call the same instance and do the same task but it fails to do it. What's the problem with my approach. How would you suggest I handle this "startActivityForResult"?